# Appearance and disappearence of header background color

Tags: html, css

I need to appear the header background color only when the mouse pointer touching the header, or clicking any part of the body.

Otherwise I need a hidden header background color.

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">
            <a  style="text-decoration:none" href="#" target="_blank">about.me</a>
            <button class="button">Log In </button>
            <button class="button">Create your page!</button>
        </div><!-- #header -->

        <div id="content">
          <div id="image">
               <center><img src="../../../../../wamp/www/check_php/IMG_9079.JPG"></center>
               <div class="clear_both" />&nbsp;</div>
               <div class="sub">
                <p align="center"><button class="button2">View my photos</button></p>
                <div class="clear_both" />&nbsp;</div>
                <p align="left">This is the power of a common man</p>
           </div> 
       </div><!-- #content -->


        <div id="footer">
           <p>Introduce yourself with a free, one-page website.
            <button class="button1">Get Started </button></p>
        </div><!-- #footer -->

    </div><!-- #wrapper -->

</body>
```

Comment: What language are you using? Any example code? You're going to get zero help without at least giving us something to go on! See [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help.

Comment: using html and css

Comment: You still need to include a :[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your code

Comment: this is not a problem. its a task to add these feature too

Answer (score 0):

add a class to your  in html:

```
       <div id="header" class="header_navi">
            <a  style="text-decoration:none" href="#" target="_blank">about.me</a>
            <button class="button">Log In </button>
            <button class="button">Create your page!</button>
        </div><!-- #header -->
```

add this to your css:

```
.header_navi {
     background-color:transparent;
}

.header_navi:hover {
     background-color:red;
}
```